# IOS Chart / MPAndroidChart. Axis Height

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts

I need to give the x-axis labels more space. Is this possible?

If you see the green box, the axis' labels are cut off.

I have tried this but with no effect:

```
xAxis.labelHeight = CGFloat(40)
```

[image]

I just added the colors to show the areas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solutions for give more space to labels in charts

```
yourGraphView.setViewPortOffsets(left: 35, top: 15, right: 20, bottom: 30)
```

It will set offset of view in charts.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to add padding around the whole chart and that gave the labels the space to show properly.

```
Chart.minOffset = CGFloat(20.0)
```

I hope this helps.